# Returning an ObjectList from RTTI in delphi

Tags: delphi, rtti, delphi-10.1-berlin

i'm calling method inside an object and i'm trying to stay very dynamic in the way i'm doing it and i came to a problem where my return type is a list of some objects, i thought about using TObjectList the problem now is that rtti returns a TValue and i don't fully understand how i can convert it to TObjectList. I thought casting the TValue as TObject since theoritically TObjectList is an object but it didn't work. Do you guys have any idea how i can possibly achieve this?

That's the function i'm speaking about.

```
   function TMyClass.ExecMethodAndRet(MethodName: string;
      Args: array of TValue): TObjectList<TObject>;
    var
     R : TRttiContext;
     T : TRttiType;
     M : TRttiMethod;
    begin
      T := R.GetType(FMyObject.ClassInfo);
      for M in t.GetMethods do
        if (m.Parent = t) and (UpperCase(m.Name) = UpperCase(MethodName))then
        begin
          result := M.Invoke(FMyObject, Args); <- problem here can't cast to TObjectList
        end;
    end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return:

```
Result := M.Invoke(Self, Args).AsType<TObjectList<TObject>>;
```

P.S. don't forget to initialize return value, ideally at the beginning of your function body.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `AsType` on the `TValue` with the correct parameter. (see [doc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Rtti.TValue.AsType))

If you in fact have a `TObjectList<TObject>` then this should be passed. If you have some `TObjectList<T>` where T is some other class you need to do a hardcast like this:

```
Result := TObjectList<TObject>(M.Invoke(FMyObject, Args).AsObject);
```

By doing so you basically fake covariance. However keep in mind that because you can add objects to your returned `TObjectList<TObject>` you are losing type safety regarding what element type it really has and the list itself does not check that. (see [my article about co- and contravariance](http://delphisorcery.blogspot.de/2014/10/generics-and-variance.html)).

Comment: Thanks for the info.